# Date comparison in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Is there a way to compare two dates in the same table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date_1 = date_2;
```

I am looking for the simplest approach to do this as part of an update statement.

Comment: what you have tried and where you are facing problem?

Comment: do you have `date_1` & `date_2` as two fields in your table...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Simple as that.

Have a look at the [`date` / `time` data types in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

You may have to pay special attention if your "date", in fact, is a `timestamp`. By default up to 6 fractional digits are saved, can be tricky with the equality operator. You might cast to `timestamp(0)` to round to seconds or use `date_trunc()` to truncate to one of various time units.

Comment: Unbelievable! I left 'where' out of my query when I copied it in to a new scratch pad. Thanks for taking the time, folks!